# Defining Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, matrix-equations, formal-languages

I have a question, which I have changed slightly, but I do not understand 'the phrasing'  of the question and the notation used:

$Q:$ Write explicitly the matrix $\mathbf{W} = [w_{ij}] $,  where $ [w_{ij}] =i^2 +j$. 
( $\mathbf{W} $ is a $3 \times 3 $ matrix).

I do not understand the phrase 'explicitly'. I think the question means repersent the matrix $\mathbf{W} $, using the definition, generally?

And i do not understand the notation '$\mathbf{W} = [w_{ij}] $'.

I thought the notation above  meant the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column? Crucially, how are you meant to define a matrix, given $ [w_{ij}] =i^2 +j$?

Comment: What's the upper right entry of $W$?

Comment: @littleO what is a upper right entry? Just the 'element' in the top right corner of the matrix?

Comment: What number goes in the first row, third column of $W$?

Comment: @littleO that is all i am given.

Comment: $i$ is the row index and $j$ is the column index. So for the entry in the first row, third column we have $i=1,j=3$. So $i^2 + j = 1 + 3  = 4$. So the upper right entry of $W$ is $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks you to write out all elements of
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}w_{11}&w_{12}&w_{13}\\w_{21}&w_{22}&w_{23}\\w_{31}&w_{32}&w_{33}\end{array}\right]$$
explicitly.

For example,
$$w_{12}=1^2+2=3.$$

Comment: Brilliant, understood.

Comment: @Gurjinder: have you ever considered "accepting" an answer to your questions?